# React Router nested routing in the base url

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I modified the sample given in React Router nested routing in the [docs](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/nesting) to setup nested routing in the base url, like [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-nesting-164ih).

I want nested routing like `/Home1`  and `/Home2`  directly under the root url.

```js
export default function NestingExample() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <Link to="/">Home</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/topics">Topics</Link>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <hr />
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/">
            <Home />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/topics">
            <Topics />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

function Home() {
  let { path, url } = useRouteMatch();
  console.log({url, path});

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Homes</h2>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <Link to="/home1">Home 1</Link> 
          {/* also tried   <Link to={`${url}/home1`}>Home 1</Link> */}
        </li>
        <li>
        <Link to="/home2">Home 2</Link>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <Switch>
        <Route exact path={path}>
          <h3>Please select a home.</h3>
        </Route>
        <Route path={`${path}/home1`}>
          <Home1 />
        </Route>
        <Route path={`${path}/home2`}>
          <Home2 />
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    </div>
  );
}

function Home1() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h3>Home1 Content</h3>
    </div>
  );
}

function Home2() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h3>Home2 Content</h3>
    </div>
  );
}
```

No error displays in the browser, but Home1 page does not display. 
Isn't it possible to setup nested routing directly under the root?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to reorder your routes so the base route is the last route within the stack(using the strict keyword)

eg.

```js
<Switch>
    <Route strict path="/users" component={UsersRoutes} />
    <Route strict path="/" compoent={PublicRoutes} />
</Switch>
```

And with this, each page can render their own `Not Found` pages.

eg.

```js
// within PublicRoutes
<Switch>
    <Route exact path={path} component={() => <h1>Public Page</h1>} />
    <Route path="*" component={() => <h1>Not found</h1>} />
</Switch>
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-nesting-025cn?file=/example.js

Comment: Can you please show a running example in codesandbox by forking mine?

Comment: @SuleymanSah here you go. I updated the response. You can upvote this to help others out there.

Answer (score 0):

I did not try this, but my guess is by using the "exact" keyword in the route of your top router, the nested structure does not match the url anymore. If you remove the property, does it work?

More information: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/exact-bool

Comment: Removing the exact there causes all the urls go to the base home route.

Comment: Move that route to the bottom of the routes :)

Comment: I tried, but same result. You can play with my playground if you have access to computer.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating a seperate `/home` route, and redirected `/` to `/home` to be able to use nested routing inside the home.

But I am still interested in a more clever answer.

```
export default function NestingExample() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <Link to="/">Home</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/topics">Topics</Link>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <hr />
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/">
            <Redirect to="/home" />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/home">
            <Home />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/topics">
            <Topics />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

function Home() {
  let { path, url } = useRouteMatch();

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Homes</h2>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <Link to={`${url}/home1`}>Home 1</Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link to={`${url}/home2`}>Home 2</Link>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <Switch>
        <Route exact path={path}>
          <h3>Please select a home.</h3>
        </Route>
        <Route path={`${path}/home1`}>
          <Home1 />
        </Route>
        <Route path={`${path}/home2`}>
          <Home2 />
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    </div>
  );
}

function Home1() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h3>Home1 Content</h3>
    </div>
  );
}

function Home2() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h3>Home2 Content</h3>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that react-router doesn't strip trailing slashes from `path` and `url` for you.

So at the root path: `path === '/'`

So when you concatenate that:

```
 <Route exact path={`${path}/home1`}>
```

You end up with

```
 <Route exact path="//home">
```

Which doesn't match any route

The easiest way to counter this is to normalize the path and url variables by removing the trailing slash

```js
let { path, url } = useRouteMatch();
//strip trailing slashes
path = path.replace(/\/$/, '');
url = url.replace(/\/$/, '');
```

Your full example would be

```js
export default function NestingExample() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <Link to="/">Home</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/topics">Topics</Link>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <hr />
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/">
            <Home />
          </Route>
          {/** Note That both "/" and "/home" will work */}
          <Route path="/home">
            <Home />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/topics">
            <Topics />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

function Home() {
  let { path, url } = useRouteMatch();
  //strip trailing slashes
  path = path.replace(/\/$/, '');
  url = url.replace(/\/$/, '');

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Homes</h2>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <Link to={`${url}/home1`}>Home 1</Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link to={`${url}/home2`}>Home 2</Link>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <Switch>
        <Route exact path={${path}/}>
          <h3>Please select a home.</h3>
        </Route>
        <Route exact path={`${path}/home1`}>
          <Home1 />
        </Route>
        <Route exact path={`${path}/home2`}>
          <Home2 />
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    </div>
  );
}

function Home1() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h3>Home1 Content</h3>
    </div>
  );
}

function Home2() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h3>Home2 Content</h3>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I made a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-nesting-03o90?file=/example.js) with your solution. Home works but Topics don't work.

Comment: This doesn't work as mentioned by @SuleymanSah. I posted one that works below.